# how a pointer to a struct member keeps the struct alive in Go

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Given the following golang code:

```golang
type Pointer struct { x, y int }

func foo(p *Pointer) *int {
    return &p.y
}
```

[CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:go,selection:(endColumn:28,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:28,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:28,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:28,startLineNumber:5),source:%27package+foo%0A%0Atype+Pointer+struct+%7B+x,+y+int+%7D%0A%0Afunc+foo(p+*Pointer)+*int+%7B%0A++++return+%26p.y%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Go+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gl1180,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:go,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27amd64+gc+1.18+(Go,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) shows that `return &p.y` compiles to

```
TESTB   AL, (AX)
ADDQ    $8, AX
RET
```

It's easy to understand. `TESTB` is a null check, then `ADDQ` produce a pointer to `p.y` by adding offset of `Pointer::y` to `p`.

What I don't understand is, given a pointer to `p.y`, how does the garbage collector knows it's not just an arbitrary `*int`, but a pointer to a `Pointer::y`, so `p` must remain alive as long as a pointer to `p.y` is still alive?

Comment: The garbage collector knows about all objects and their sizes in the heap. In this example, if `p` is in the heap, then the garbage collector would know that a pointer points to a region owned by a struct, thus keeps the struct alive.

Comment: @BurakSerdar with what kind of data structure and algorithm? GC need to be fast, so the time complexity should be `O(1)`, right?

Comment: I am not sure about the internals of the GC, but I don't think it is O(1). Nevertheless, if you have a sorted array of objects in memory, you can find if a pointer falls into a range using a binary search.

Comment: gc (the compiler)'s GC (Garbage Collector) is a kind of mark-and-sweep. you can find more information here: https://tip.golang.org/doc/gc-guide

Answer (score 3):

After reading the [source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/85a482fc244f6f118b1d063063a51eb8b0feadd8/src/runtime/mbitmap.go#L391) I found the answer.

1. Go use arena / span based allocation.
2. Arenas and spans are aligned with pages, so it's trivial to calculate which arena is the pointer pointing to.
3. There's a global vector stores metadata of all arenas and spans.
4. Each span has a fixed "element size". All objects in the same span have the same size.
5. Given the pointer `p`, base address of span `b` and element size of span `s`, we know the pointer is pointing n-th element in the span, where `n = (p - b) / s`.
6. So the address of n-th object in the span `b + s * n`, which needs to be marked as alive.